# Sharing states between SwiftUI CoreData tabs

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm developing an app with two tabs. The first tab is responsible for managing the state of a CoreData entity, while the second tab depends on reading this state.

However, I'm facing an issue. When I change the state in one tab, it doesn't reflect the change in the other tab.

AppFile

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct GenosApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.surfaceColor)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
            persistenceController.save()
        }
    }
}
```

PersistenceController

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

struct PersistenceController {
    // A singleton for our entire app to use
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    // Storage for Core Data
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    // A test configuration for SwiftUI previews
    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let controller = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)

        // Create 10 example metrics
        for index in 0 ..< 10 {
            let metric = Metric(context: controller.container.viewContext)

            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let oneDayAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: (index + 1) * -1, to: Date())!

            metric.username = "Rodrigodh"
            metric.balance = 20 * Float(index)
            metric.date = oneDayAgo

            if index < 3 {
                metric.exercise = true
            }

            if index == 0 {
                metric.date = Date()
                metric.balance = 20
            }
        }

        return controller
    }()

    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to save changes")
            }
        }
    }

    // An initializer to load Core Data, optionally able
    // to use an in-memory store.
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Main")

        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TabExample (HomeView)

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Metric.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default) private var metrics: FetchedResults<Metric>

    var todaysMetric: Metric? {
        let currentDate = Date()

        let filteredTodayMetrics = metrics.filter { metric in
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            if metric.date == nil {
                return false
            }

            return calendar.isDate(metric.date!, inSameDayAs: currentDate)
        }

        return filteredTodayMetrics.first
    }

    var sortedMetrics: [Metric] {
        let sortdeByDate = metrics.sorted { $0.date ?? nil ?? Date() > $1.date ?? Date() }
        return sortdeByDate
    }

    func updateExercise() {
        todaysMetric?.exercise = !(todaysMetric?.exercise ?? false)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                CustomBackground()
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HeaderView()

                    Text("Metas diárias")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.textColor)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.top, 10.0)
                    MoneyGoalProgressView(metric: todaysMetric ?? nil)
                        .padding(.top, 5.0)

                    ExerciseGoalView(metric: todaysMetric ?? nil, updateExercise: updateExercise).padding(.top, 5.0)

                    Text("Histórico")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.textColor)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.top, 10.0)

                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: 16.0) {
                            ForEach(sortedMetrics) { metric in HistoryCardView(metric: metric) }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 20.0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let persistenceController = PersistenceController.preview
        let viewContext = persistenceController.container.viewContext

        return HomeView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
    }
}
```

I even attempted to move the @FetchRequest to the ContentView and handle the results from there, but it didn't work.